# How to remove vertical empty space in TeX?

Tags: errors, vertical-spacing

I have a code in TeX and I need to add a footnote at the first page, I did it, but a problem appeared. When I compile the code without the footnote, everything is ok. But after adding the footnote a strange vertical empty space appeared, please see the picture. In both texlive and miktex. I googled the problem but didn't find anything. Thank you for your answer.

[image: vertical empty space]

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{docmute}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{misccorr}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsbib}
\usepackage{tikz}
\geometry{twoside,
layoutheight=241mm,layoutwidth=171mm,
layouthoffset=19.5mm,layoutvoffset=28mm,
inner=27mm,outer=17mm,
top=33mm,bottom=21mm,
showcrop}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Теорема}
\newtheorem{sled}{Следствие}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Лемма}

%\usepackage{mathdots}
\begin{document}
\footnote[1]{%
    ...
 }
{\footnotesize
\begin{verbatim}
...
\end{verbatim}
} 
...

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Just a wild guess: Probably `\raggedbottom` helps.

Comment: Note that the code you provided does not replicate the problem on the image. Please update. My guess: you either have a large unbreakable piece of math on the next page, or a `\begin{figure}[H]`

Comment: @daleif I cannot even see the image well!!

Comment: Well, the code is very big (18 pages). How should I add it?

Comment: ...Yep, looks like I have big formula on the next page. What should I do now?..

Comment: Does inserting `\allowdisplaybreaks` before the big formula help?

Comment: Assuming it is an align, you could add comments to it using `\intertext` or `\ shortintertext ` the latter is from mathtools. An align is allowed to break at one of these comments. Alternatively you can allow all aligns to be able to break but that is not always advisable

Comment: We are not asking for code for all 18 pages, just enough to replicate the problem

Comment: Please edit your posting to show the big formula that's currently placed at the top of p. 11.